# NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10256a1b0'

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a view controller in which i'm parsing an xml file and getting its values in dictionary, i'm trying to get the values in the labels but my app is crashing by showing this error `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10256a1b0'`

My code to get values from dictionary are these,

```
 NSLog(@"string: %@", str);
NSDictionary *xmlDoc = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithXMLString:str];
NSLog(@"dictionary: %@", xmlDoc);

for (NSDictionary * oneCustomer in xmlDoc)
{
    // Create a new Customer record

    _lblID.text = [oneCustomer objectForKey:@"_id"];
    NSLog(@"Reg: %@ ",_lblID.text);

    _lblAlert.text = [oneCustomer objectForKey:@"_topic"];
    NSLog(@"Make: %@ ",_lblAlert.text);

    _lblxref.text = [oneCustomer objectForKey:@"xref"];

    NSLog(@"Type: %@ ",_lblxref.text);

    _lbltext.text = [oneCustomer objectForKey:@"text"];
    NSLog(@"Model: %@ ", _lbltext.text);

    _lblgraphic.text = [oneCustomer objectForKey:@"explanation"];
    NSLog(@"Model: %@ ",_lblgraphic.text);

    _lblprompt.text = [oneCustomer objectForKey:@"prompt"];
    NSLog(@"Model: %@ ",_lblprompt.text);

   _lblvoice.text = [oneCustomer objectForKey:@"_id"];
    NSLog(@"Model: %@ ", _lblvoice.text);

    //roils = [oneCustomer objectForKey:@"recommended oil"];
    //NSLog(@"Model: %@ ",roils);
}
```

How to remove this error?
This is my dictionary ,

```
dictionary: {
"__name" = QF;
"_category" = "C&M";
"_id" = AB2001;
"_ni_exempt" = no;
"_topic" = Alertness;
answers =     {
    answer =         (
                    {
            "_correct" = no;
            text = "give an arm signal as well as using your indicators";
        },
                    {
            "_correct" = no;
            text = "signal so that other drivers can slow down for you";
        },
                    {
            "_correct" = yes;
            text = "look over your shoulder for a final check";
        },
                    {
            "_correct" = no;
            text = "select a higher gear than normal";
        }
    );
};
question =     {
    explanation =         {
        text = "If you want to make a U-turn, slow down and ensure that the road is clear in both directions. Make sure that the road is wide enough to carry out the manoeuvre safely.";
        voice =             {
            "_id" = "AB2001-2";
        };
    };
    prompt = "Mark one answer";
    text = "Before you make a U-turn in the road, you should";
    voice =         {
        "_id" = "AB2001-1";
    };
    xref = "DES s4, DES s9, HC r159-161";
};
```

I have to extract the values from this dictionary all the values how can i get this?

Comment: Apparently at some point `oneCustomer` is a `NSString` object, not a `NSDictionary`, so you can't do `[oneCustomer objectForKey:someKey]` on it and causes the crash.

Comment: so how to fix it now? How can i get the values from my dictionary? @Larme

Comment: It's NOT a dictionary.  Could you give us the value of `str`? I have some guess like why the for loop... So `_lblID.text = [xmlDoc objectForKey:@"_id"];` instead of `_lblID.text = [oneCustomer objectForKey:@"_id"];` (and so on), but that's wild guesses...

Comment: i have added dictionary please check it .@Larme

Comment: Remove `for (NSDictionary * oneCustomer in xmlDoc)`, and just do `_lblID.text = [xmlDoc objectForKey:@"_id"];` (and so and replacing `oneCustomer` by `xmlDoc`.

Comment: when i do this it only gives me value of id and when i try to get other values from dictionary it show null, like for text it shows null value, how to get other values except id. @Larme

Comment: You clearly need to understand the structure of your dictionary, all its "sublevels"... You have 5 times a key `text` at some point of the hierarchy, how are you supposed to make it as "one"?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps you,

```
-(void)fetchValuesFromDictioanry:(NSDictionary*)xmlDict
{
    for (NSString *string in [xmlDict allKeys])
    {
        if ([[xmlDict valueForKey:string] isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
        {
            [self fetchValuesFromDictioanry:[xmlDict valueForKey:string]];
        }
        else if ([[xmlDict valueForKey:string] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
        {

            if ([string isEqualToString:@"_id"] && [[xmlDict valueForKey:string] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
            {
                _lblID.text = [xmlDict valueForKey:@"_id"];
            }
            else
           {
               NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromClass([[xmlDict valueForKey:string] class]));
           }
            NSLog(@"Model: %@ ", [xmlDict valueForKey:string]);

          //Set here other labels
        }
        else if ([[xmlDict valueForKey:string] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
        {
            for (NSDictionary *dictionary in [xmlDict valueForKey:string]) {

                [self fetchValuesFromDictioanry:dictionary];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can call like this,

```
[self fetchValuesFromDictioanry:xmlDoc];
```

Comment: Bro i have parsed the file , the issue is that the dictionary i'm getting i want to extract values from that. @Hitesh Sultaniya

Comment: @Nabeel When you will pass your dictionary to this function you will be able to get all the values that you need, sorry for the method name but this will just iterate through you dictionary and will print values when any value for key is string and also you won't get any error

Comment: How to call this method in view did load? @ Hitesh Sultaniya

Comment: @Nabeel please check updated answer but argument should a dictionary

Comment: Bro it is only showing values of id and topic from dictionary and for other it is showing null. @ Hitesh Sultaniya

Comment: @Nabeel try to check the class of the values you are fetching those may be something else means may other than string

Comment: i'm just fetching it from the dictionary by their name, but it is showing null. @Hitesh Sultaniya

Comment: Never use `valueForKey` unless you can explain why you explicitly need KVC, can you?

Comment: so how can i get the values from it? @vadian